# Can't find / render JSP file with Spring Boot & MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm trying to build my first application with Spring in IntelliJ IDEA, however I can't make it find and/or render the JSP file called home.jsp. Please see the screenshots. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you have any questions about my setup, pls leave a comment and I'll answer them.

Here's my list of dependencies in Gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:8.0.30')
    runtime('org.hsqldb:hsqldb')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') 
}
```

[image: Error message]
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: where is the Hello!.jsp page?

Comment: In WebMvcConfig. can you remove the pub folder. I did not find any "pub" folder in your project

Comment: @FarazDurrani Note the ResponseBody annotation there. I just did that to verify if the controller works and it did. There's no JSP needed there, right?

Comment: @Shaheer That just means I'm mapping URL /pub/** to path /resources/ so pub is not a real path as far as I know. In the console I see: Mapped URL path [/pub/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]

Answer (score 0):

I put the JSP files under /webapp/WEB-INF/views/ and now it works. I think it has something to do with the webapp directory which wasn't automatically created by intellij. Tomcat probably looks here for some files.